# #1442 - Can't update table ... in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, triggers, procedure

I have this situation:
Two table in two databases: 
1st: `persone`.`T_Persone` that contain detailed information about workers plus two fields empty by default: `user_id` and `username`;
2nd: `joomla`.`fe48y_users` that contain information of user in the CMS Joomla including `id` and `username`.
I created a procedure that insert a new user in joomla and return user_id and username of new user created.
I also created also 2 triggers (on update and on insert) that call the procedure and set user_id and username on `T_Persone` table.
I also created a trigger on delete of `joomla`.`fe48y_users` that update `persone`.`T_Persone` and set null to `user_id` and `username` fields.

This is the procedure:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `persone_users_upd`(IN `in_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED, IN `new_email` VARCHAR(255), IN `old_email` VARCHAR(255), OUT `out_user_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED, OUT `out_username` VARCHAR(255))
BEGIN
    DECLARE has_email Boolean;
    DECLARE my_user_id INT;
    DECLARE my_username VARCHAR(255);
    DECLARE my_name VARCHAR(255);

    SELECT (CASE new_email WHEN '' THEN FALSE ELSE TRUE END) INTO @has_email;

    IF @has_email THEN
        SELECT CONCAT(`Nome`,' ',`Cognome`), COALESCE(`CF`,LOWER(SUBSTR(new_email, 1, INSTR(new_email, '@') - 1))) INTO @my_name, @my_username FROM `T_Persone` WHERE `IDPersona` = in_id;
        IF new_email = old_email THEN
            INSERT INTO `spmsf`.`fe48y_users` (`name`, `username`, `email`, `password`, `block`, `sendEmail`, `registerDate`, `lastvisitDate`, `activation`, `params`, `lastResetTime`, `resetCount`, `otpKey`, `otep`, `requireReset`) VALUES
(@my_name, @my_username, new_email, '<omissis>', 0, 1, NOW(), '0000-00-00 00:00:00', '', '{"admin_style":"","admin_language":"","language":"","editor":"","helpsite":"","timezone":"Europe/Rome"}', '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 0, '', '', 0) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `name` = VALUES(`name`), `email` = VALUES(`email`);
        ELSE
            UPDATE `spmsf`.`fe48y_users` SET `email` = @my_email WHERE `email` = new_email;
        END IF;
        SELECT `id`, `username` INTO @my_user_id,  @my_username FROM `spmsf`.`fe48y_users` WHERE `email` = new_email;

        INSERT IGNORE INTO `spmsf`.`fe48y_user_usergroup_map` (`user_id`,`group_id`) VALUES (@my_user_id, 10);

        SET out_user_id=@my_user_id, out_username=@my_username;
    END IF;
END
```

these are the triggers on `T_Persone`:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `persone_del` AFTER DELETE ON `T_Persone`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
IF OLD.`user_id` IS NOT NULL THEN
DELETE FROM `spmsf`.`fe48y_users` WHERE `id` = OLD.`user_id`;
DELETE FROM `spmsf`.`fe48y_user_usergroup_map` WHERE `user_id` = OLD.`user_id`;
END IF;
END

CREATE TRIGGER `persone_ins` BEFORE INSERT ON `T_Persone`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    CALL persone_users_upd(NEW.`IDPersona`,COALESCE(NEW.`Email`,NEW.`Email_alt`),COALESCE(NEW.`Email`,NEW.`Email_alt`), @user_id, @username);
    SET NEW.`user_id` = @user_id, NEW.`username` = @username;
END

CREATE TRIGGER `persone_upd` BEFORE UPDATE ON `T_Persone`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    CALL persone_users_upd(NEW.`IDPersona`,COALESCE(NEW.`Email`,NEW.`Email_alt`),COALESCE(OLD.`Email`,OLD.`Email_alt`), @user_id, @username);
    SET NEW.`user_id` = @user_id, NEW.`username` = @username;
END
```

and this is the trigger on `fe48y_users` delete:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `users_del` BEFORE DELETE ON `fe48y_users`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    DECLARE my_user_id Int;

    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO @my_user_id FROM `personale`.`T_Persone` WHERE `user_id` = OLD.`id`;
    IF @my_user_id > 0 THEN
        UPDATE `personale`.`T_Persone` SET `user_id` = NULL, `username` = NULL WHERE `user_id` = OLD.`id`;
    END IF;
END
```

SO, I have two problems:

1st: When I try to delete a user in `fe48y_users` I have the error

```
#1442 - Can't update table 'fe48y_users' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.
```

2nd: When I insert a new person it don't appear in 'fe48y_users' but when I update it than appear.